# AppLink isn't working in Flutter application in debug mode even though the assetlinks are verified and valid

Tags: android, flutter, deep-linking, android-app-links

I have been trying to implement AppLink in my Flutter application for android which is currently in development/debug mode, but the AppLink doesn't work. When I hit the URL through browser in my mobile which is running the Flutter application in debug/development mode, the app doesn't opens. I suppose there is some problem inside the Flutter app implementation.

#### Steps I have tried

1. Created the `assetlinks.json` file and added the following details:

   ```
     [
       {
         "relation": [
           "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
         ],
         "target": {
           "namespace": "android_app",
           "package_name": "com.foxjek.fox_jek_user",
           "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
            "73:EA:74:0C:B4:6B:99:37:C0:CF:B9:BD:54:EB:2C:51:04:5A:3A:6A:0E:64:0B:27:B8:73:B2:51:4B:B3:CE:F9"
           ]
         }
       }
     ]
   ```
2. And uploaded it on the server on the `root` directory under the folder `.well-known` and tested through the [Google Digital Asset Links](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator) and the Test is success.
3. Now I have installed the [uni_link 0.5.1](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links/example) library for AppLinking implementation by following the steps defined [here](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links/install)
4. After that I have followed the following steps to setup everything:

   - Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml` file under the `android/app/src/main` directory.
     Inside the `<activity>` tag (usually named `MainActivity`), I have added the `<intent-filter>` element:

     ```
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="com.foxjek.fox_jek_user">

            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
            <uses-feature
                android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
                android:required="true" />

            <!-- Provide required visibility configuration for API level 30 and above -->
            <queries>

                <intent>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <data android:scheme="sms" />
                </intent>
                <!-- If your app makes calls -->
                <intent>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
                    <data android:scheme="tel" />
                </intent>


                <!-- If your app emails -->
                <intent>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
                </intent>
                <!-- If your sends SMS messages -->
                <intent>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
                    <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                </intent>
                <intent>
                    <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
                </intent>

                <package android:name="com.facebook.katana" />
            </queries>

            <application
                android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                android:supportsRtl="true"
                android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
                <receiver
                    android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver"
                    android:exported="false">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </receiver>
                <receiver
                    android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver"
                    android:exported="false" />


                <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

                <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
                    android:value="high_importance_channel" />
                <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
                    android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />
                <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
                    android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />

                <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                    android:value="@string/google_api_key" />

                <meta-data
                    android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
                    android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

                <meta-data
                    android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken"
                    android:value="@string/facebook_client_token" />

                <activity
                    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
                    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
                    android:exported="false"
                    android:label="@string/app_name" />
                <activity
                    android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
                    android:exported="true">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                        <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>

                <!--<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider2226807840719365"
                    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
                    android:exported="true" />-->
                <activity
                    android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />

                <activity
                    android:name=".MainActivity"
                    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
                    android:exported="true"
                    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                    android:launchMode="singleTop"
                    android:showWhenLocked="true"
                    android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
                    android:turnScreenOn="true"
                    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

                    <meta-data
                        android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                        android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />

                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    </intent-filter>

                    <meta-data
                        android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                        android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                    <!-- App Links -->
                    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with https://YOUR_HOST -->
                        <data
                            android:scheme="https"
                            android:host="user-api.slim-surface-app.com" />
                    </intent-filter>

                </activity>

                <meta-data
                    android:name="flutterEmbedding"
                    android:value="2" />
            </application>


        </manifest>
     ```
   - Dart code updated as:

     ```
        void main() {
          runApp(const MyApp());
          initUniLinks();
        }
        void initUniLinks() async {
          // Initialize the UniLinks plugin
          print("Initialize the UniLinks plugin");
          try {
            await getInitialLink();
          } on PlatformException {
            // Handle exception/error as needed
            print("Handle exception/error as needed");
          }

          // Listen for incoming deep links
          // Attach a listener to the stream
          print("Listen for incoming deep links");
          linkStream.listen((String? uri) {
            // Handle the deep link URI
            print("Handle the deep link URI");
            print(uri);


          } , onError: (err) {
            // Handle error, if any
            print("Handle error, if any");
          });
        }
     ```
   - rebuild and reinstall Flutter app on the device for the updates to take effect.
5. But, now when I hit the domain your-domain.com in browser in device, the same device which is running the Flutter app in debug mode, the device don't identify the DeepLink/AppLink to open the app.

#### What I'm Expecting

1. Whenever I open the your-domain.com in my mobile browser the same mobile which is running th Flutter application in debug mode should redirect it to Flutter app and should open the app quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the app by running this command
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/set-up-app-links

```
adb shell 'am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW \
    -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE \
    -d "http://<web-domain>/details"' \
    <package name>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100 percent sure, but this seems a design scheme only for debug version.
Except the adb test method, you can manually set the applinks in Android phone Settings > Apps > Default apps > Open links.